# Unplanned shut off when drawing 1A from TPS2596 e-fuse IC

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I'm trying to build a power bank and whenever I draw ~1A the protection circuit of the TPS 2596 cuts the voltage, but I have the current limit set to 2A with a 453ohm resistor. When drawing 1A the voltage drops only 0.1v, but the shutoff still activates. Below is the schematic and the PCB design. Thank you so much!
[image: Schematic]
[image: PCB layout]

Comment: What is the voltage at the ILM pin (the current limiter is triggered at 600 mV)? Can you check with an oscilloscope whether there are any transients?

Comment: What's your power supply's current limit set at?

Comment: Does the UVLO trigger before the OCP? Your tracks are rather small for 2A (Picutres...). Also: Are there any soldering issues? Sometimes SMD-Resistors don't solder perfectly -altough they look like it - when done at home. You could use a soldering iron and rework all Resistor pads.